# Unit test of method with CompletableFuture inside

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, completable-future

I have method which in async way calls `connector.runSomeService(data)` and handles the response in method `handleServiceResponse(res, node)`.

```
public void runServiceOnAllNodes(Collection<Node> nodes, Object data) {
    nodes.parallelStream().forEach(node -> {
        CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> response = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(()-> connector.runSomeService(data));
        response.exceptionally(ex -> {
                    log.error("OMG...OMG!!!")
                    return null;
                })
                .thenAcceptAsync(res -> handleServiceResponse(res, node));
    });
}


private void handleServiceResponse(ResponseEntity res, Node node) {
    if (res.isOK) {
        node.setOKStatus();
    } else {
        node.setFailStatus();
    }
    dbService.saveNode(node);
}
```

Try to create unit test but when I try to verify if response is properly handled, the result of UT is non deterministic.

```
@Test
public void testRunServiceOnAllNodes() {
    // given
    List<Collector> nodes = Arrays.asList(node1, node2, node3);
    when(connector.runSomeService(eq(node1), eq(data))).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body("{message:OK}"));
    when(connector.runSomeService(eq(node2), eq(data))).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(""));
    when(connector.runSomeService(eq(node3), eq(data))).thenThrow(new ResourceAccessException(""));

    // when
    engine.runServiceOnAllNodes(data, collectors);

    // then
    verify(connector, times(1)).runSomeService(eq(node1), eq(data));
    verify(connector, times(1)).runSomeService(eq(node2), eq(data));
    verify(connector, times(1)).runSomeService(eq(node3), eq(data));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(connector);
    assertEquals(node1.getStatus(), "OK");
    assertEquals(node2.getStatus(), "Fail");
}
```

It can end with a few different results eg.

```
Wanted but not invoked:
connector.runSomeService(node2);

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
connector.runSomeService(node1);
```

or

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
connector.runSomeService(node1);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
connector.deployFileset(node2);
```

or sometimes it ends with success.

It is clear that the time of execution `connector.runSomeService()` and the time of the verification can interlace. The order of this two actions is not deterministic.

Using sleep sucks. Tried to gather all responses and calling future.get()

```
// when
engine.runServiceOnAllNodes(data, collectors);
for (CompletableFuture future : engine.getResponses()) {
    future.get();
}
```

but I'm getting some exception but I still have the feeling that this way also sucks, isn't it?

Comment: Do you consider `Awaitility` also ugly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing the `runServiceOnAllNodes` method to return a `Future` so your test, and, as a bonus, normal clients as well, can explicitly wait for the async behavior to finish.

```
public Future<Void> runServiceOnAllNodes(Collection<Node> nodes, Object data) {
    return nodes.parallelStream().map(node -> {
        CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> response = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(()-> connector.runSomeService(data));
        return response.exceptionally(ex -> {
            LOGGER.error("OMG...OMG!!!");
            return null;
        })
        .thenAcceptAsync(res -> handleServiceResponse(res, node));
    })
    .reduce(CompletableFuture::allOf).orElseGet(() -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null));
}
```

In your test, it is then simply a matter of calling `get()` on the future prior to making assertions and verifications.

Answer (score 0):

I had a unit testing scenario where CompletableFuture was used inside method and then .get() was called to retrieve the value. Something like this:

```
public class SomeService {
    public Object getData(String id) {
        ..some code...
        CompletableFuture taskToComplete = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executor);
        ..some code...
        Data data = taskToComplete.get();
        ..some code...
    }
}
```

In my testing class, I have followed these steps:

Created a mock object of CompletableFuture, something like this.

```
@Mock
CompletableFuture<T> detailsTask;
```

Assigned completed value of response, something like

```
@Test
void testGetDetails() {
    detailsTask = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
}
```

Lastly, mock the static supplyAsync method.

```
completableFutureMock.when(() -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(any(), any(Executor.class))).thenReturn(detailsTask);
```

Final change will look something like this:

```
class Test {
    @Mock
    CompletableFuture<T> detailsTask;

    @Test
    void testGetDetails() {
        detailsTask = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(data);
        try (MockedStatic<CompletableFuture> completableFutureMock = Mockito.mockStatic(CompletableFuture.class)) {
            completableFutureMock.when(() -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(any(), any(Executor.class))).thenReturn(detailsTask);
        }
    }
}
```